# Do not want to pass all unnecessary parameters in stored Procedure

Tags: sql

i have a stroed procedure having two events one is insertion and another one is deletion
using flag. when i have to delete ..i have to pass all parameters which is not actually need while delete.... i need your help to sort it out .

my code is like this..

```
ALTER     Proc Proc_Manage_Opening_Leave @ActionFlag int,@SNo int,@LEAVE_ID int,@GIVEN decimal,@GIVENMONTH int,@GIVENYEAR int,@APPROVEDBY int,@IsOpening varchar(6),@EMP_ID int
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
if(@ActionFlag=0)
BEGIN

insert into Tbl_Org_leave_log (EMP_ID,LEAVE_ID,GIVEN,GIVENMONTH,GIVENYEAR,ApprovedBy,OP_FLAG,GIVENDAY)
values(@EMP_ID,@LEAVE_ID,@GIVEN,@GIVENMONTH,@GIVENYEAR,@APPROVEDBY,
(
case
when @IsOpening='False' then 0
when @IsOpening='True' then 1
ELSE NULL
END
),
datepart(day,getdate()))
END

 IF(@ActionFlag=1)
BEGIN

delete from tbl_org_leave_log where SNo=@SNo
END


GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the best answer ..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating a seperate SPs for each action.

Answer (score 1):

Change your parameters to have default values like so:

```
alter     proc Proc_Manage_Opening_Leave
  @ActionFlag int
 ,@SNo int = null
 ,@LEAVE_ID int = null
 ,@GIVEN decimal = null
 ,@GIVENMONTH int = null
 ,@GIVENYEAR int = null
 ,@APPROVEDBY int = null
 ,@IsOpening varchar(6) = null
 ,@EMP_ID int = null
as
```

Then you don't need to provide values for them.

But I agree with Akram that you should make two separate procedures